# Jquery Mobile Popup positioning

Tags: jquery-mobile

Need help of fresh eye. Trying to position to the element. Not working, positioning to window. Testing on Safari as far as on Firefox.

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
  <ul data-role="listview" class="todo-listview ui-listview">
    <li data-row-id="1" class="outstanding ui-li-has-alt ui-first-child">
      <a href="" class="view ui-btn" data-view-id="1"></a>

$(document).on('taphold', '.todo-listview a', function() {
        console.log("DEBUG - Go popup");
      var link_name = $(this).attr('data-view-id');
      var $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
        dismissible: true,
        theme: "b",
        transition: "pop",
        positionTo: '#link_name'
        }).on("popupafterclose", function () {
    //remove the popup when closing
    $(this).remove();
    });

    $("<p/>", {
    text: "Test!"
    }).appendTo($popUp);

    $popUp.popup('open').trigger("create");  

    });
```

Thank you for your time. It works indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems:

change  `positionTo: '#link_name'` to `positionTo: '#' +link_name`

You then need to set the ID of the li `<li data-row-id="1" id="1"...`

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6w109gj5/)**